# Setting Player Name from Combo Box then show stats in Textbox from another table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am doing a Windows Form Application in C# using an SQlite database. I have a drop down which includes the Players Names taken from a table named **"Player"**. I want to show a particular statistic of the chosen player from the `combo box` in a `textbox`, but these stats are located in another Table named `"Player_Attributes"`. Both tables include the Player ID which are common for both tables.

Is it possible for someone show me how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

**I'm displaying the ComboBox data this way:**

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Users\nicho\Documents\nicholas2ndyearproject\database.sqlite";
            string sql = "select * from Player";
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                da.Fill(ds);
                playersListBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                playersListBox.DisplayMember = "player_name";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

private void playersListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = playersListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

**Dropdown Code**

```
private void playersListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Users\nicho\Documents\nicholas2ndyearproject\database.sqlite";
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + filename + ";Version=3;");
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT player_name, Player_Attributes.sprint_speed FROM Player JOIN Player_Attributes ON Player.player_api_id = Player_Attributes.player_api_id;"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_api_id", playersListBox.SelectedValue);
                    SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        txtRating.Text = reader["rating"].ToString();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have the ID so you just query the database again.

`string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Player_Attributes WHERE [Player ID] = {0}",ID)` in your `playersListBox_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: Thanks. I arranged the code and edited the question from yesterday. Now i have since whenever i change the Player Name from the dropdown the stats remain the same of the first player in the list and do not update

Comment: Check the updated code pls

Answer (score 0):

You need to know SQL JOIN for this statement, join needs same column on at least 2 table and use like below:

```
SELECT  (column name which are you want)
FROM Player JOIN Player_Attributes
ON players.player.id= Player_Attributes.Player.id
```

Read these values with sqldatareader and store them any collection like array, arraylist, list.

Comment: Thanks. I arranged the code and edited the question from yesterday. Now i have since whenever i change the Player Name from the dropdown the stats remain the same of the first player in the list and do not update

Comment: Share your solution or link for others

Comment: I can't share it on here but